# Do "three consecutive days" mean the same as "three straight days"?

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

Are the two phrases equivalent?

Example sentences:

> Mary had stayed in this hotel for five consecutive days.
>
> Mary had stayed in this hotel for five straight days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no difference between "consecutive" and "straight" in this context.
According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/), consecutive means "Following each other continuously.", and straight means "In continuous succession." They are listed as synonyms of one another.

**Edit:** I would use "consecutive" for clarity, see @Davo's comment

Comment: True. But there is potential for misunderstanding on the second sentence. The specific wording *Mary had stayed in this hotel for five straight days.* would make me consider that perhaps Mary did not venture out of the hotel the entire time.

Comment: @Davo I totally agree and edited my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Davo's comment to SirChregeli.

**straight** refers to a stretch of time as *uninterrupted* or *unrelieved (e.g. by a respite)* or *unvaried (e.g. in routine)*, whereas  **consecutive** means *one after the other*.

> She had to attend three consecutive two-hour meetings. She was going to be tied up for six straight hours.

Comment: You've expressed the same nuance of "distinction" that I understand here much more succinctly than I could.

Answer (score 2):

I think we have got seriously off track as a result of Davo's comment.

The original answer quoted the OED. That is reliable authority. "Five consecutive days" and "five straight days" have the same denotative meaning.

"She stayed at that hotel for five consecutive days" and "she stayed at that hotel for five straight days" denote the same thing, and neither implies that she never left the hotel's premises throughout those five days.

"She stayed inside that hotel for five consecutive days" and "she stayed inside that hotel for five straight days" denote the same thing, and both explicitly state that she immured herself in a particular place for the same duration.

So in terms of teaching someone English, the denotative meanings of "five consecutive days" and "five straight days" are the same. The potential ambiguity arises from the term "stay in the hotel," which may mean "stay inside the hotel" or "stay at the hotel." So in terms of the nuances of the English language, the phrase "stay in a hotel" may mean one of two things because both "stay" and "in" have fairly broad meanings.

Why then did Davo perceive the ambiguity in one case and not the other? The answer is that, although "consecutive" and "straight" denote the same continuity, they have slightly different connotations, with "consecutive" being invariably neutral and "straight" sometimes implying disapproval or surprise. There is nothing surprising about being a guest at the same hotel for days on end, but it may be surprising to never leave the premises for days on end. To avoid any possibility about whether "stay in the hotel" means "stay at the hotel" or "stay inside the hotel," the key word to fix is the preposition following "stay."

Comment: I don't agree with your assertion that the two expressions are "identical". The word ***consecutive*** is entirely neutral in such contexts, but (significantly more informal, imho) ***straight*** tends to imply the speaker/audience would normally *expect* there to be "gaps" in the sequence (i.e. - it's both more casual, and more emphatic).

Comment: @FumbleFingers My assertion of "identity" is to be found where exactly? In terms of connotations, I am not sure why you disagree with my "neutral" in opposition to your "neutral." And is not my "surprising" consistent with your "unexpected"? It would certainly not be unexpected for a person to stay at a hotel for five days. It might be odd to stay inside one for five days. Despite your comment, I still think that the ambiguity arises from "in."

Comment: Just because the semantics of a thing basically denote the same meaning does not mean they are stylistically the same or contextually the same. In any event, as a native speaker I see no difference in meaning between the two....

Comment: @Jeff Morrow: I can only apologise. The truth is I never actually read your last paragraph - my earlier comment (and as I now realise, unjustified downvote) were purely based on what you'd written before that. In which context I'm still not convinced that the digression into *stay **in / at** the hotel* is directly relevant to the question as posed, but I've reversed my downvote after looking at it again. Whatever - I genuinely thank you for calling me out there, and I hope you'll be satisfied with my response.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Apology accepted. No problem. I agree that my answer is not directly related to the OP. It came up as I tried to figure out how the ambiguity mentioned by Davo arose. I did not see it arising from any fundamental difference in the meaning of the terms originally questioned. I agree with you that "straight" may have the connotation of "unexpected" or "untoward," but those connotations are not invariable. The ambiguity in the preposition seems to invite those connotations, which would not be elicited with "at." Not worth arguing about.

Comment: I can't find the specific point in any free-access online dictionaries, but the full OED definition **straight** 3h *Consecutive, in unbroken sequence. **colloq.** (orig. U.S.).* supports my feeling that even today that sense is at least *somewhat* "informal". And unless I missed something, I don't think that specific point has been made anywhere on this page.

Comment: @FF I agree. Until you raised it, the colloquial aspect of "straight" was a difference that had been overlooked.